# Update not working properly with derived table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please see the query below:

```
update dbusns 
set thisdate = created 
from 
    (select 
        MAX(created) AS CREATED, DBCUSTODY.REFERENCE 
     from dbusns 
     inner join [server].Custody.DBO.dbcustody on dbusns.urns = dbcustody.reference
     where dbusns.datasetname = 'CUSTODY' 
     group by dbcustody.reference) As CustodyDateTable 
WHERE 
   dbusns.urns = CustodyDateTable.reference 
   and dbusns.urns = '1'
```

The following query returns `01/01/2011`:

```
select 
    MAX(created) AS CREATED, DBCUSTODY.REFERENCE 
from 
    dbusns 
inner join 
    server.database.DBO.dbcustody on dbusns.urns = dbcustody.reference
where 
    dbusns.datasetname = 'CUSTODY' AND DBCUSTODY.REFERENCE = '1'
```

However, the following query return `31/10/2011` (after query 1 is run):

```
select 
    THISDATE 
from 
    dbusns 
where 
    datasetname = 'CUSTODY' AND URNS = '1' --QUERY 3
```

The query below returns two rows (31/10/2011 and 01/11/2011):

```
select created 
from [server].Custody.DBO.dbcustody 
where reference = '1'
```

Why does query 3 return 31/10/2011? It should return 01/11/2011? Is this something to do with the execution plan/linked server?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to `SELECT * INTO #dbusns FROM dbusns WHERE datasetname = 'CUSTODY' AND URNS = '1'` and `SELECT * INTO #dbcustody FROM from [server].Custody.DBO.dbcustody WHERE reference = '1'`, and then, for the purpose of testing, try executing the same update on those two tables and verify the result?

Comment: @Andriy M, thanks. That is a good idea. I will try it.+1

Comment: Given your sample data, the maximum date is the one being returned.  Do you really want `MIN()` instead of `MAX()`?

Comment: @andriy M, it works if dbusns and dbcustody are on the same database server. It is the cross database that is failing. Interestingly one sever is sql 2005 and the other is sql 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` syntax seems wrong for what you want. In this case, the best way would be to use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE D
SET thisdate = T.created 
FROM dbusns D
INNER JOIN (SELECT  MAX(created) created,
                    C.reference 
            FROM dbusns 
            INNER JOIN [server].Custody.DBO.dbcustody C
                ON dbusns.urns = dbcustody.reference
            WHERE dbusns.datasetname = 'CUSTODY' 
            GROUP BY dbcustody.reference) T
    ON D.urns = T.reference
WHERE D.urns = 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried this query as well.  It did not solve the problem.

Comment: @w0051977 Can you clarify what that means?, because it should be doing what you want

Comment: Thanks.  dbcustody contains two rows for URN=1 (31/10/2011 and 01/11/2011).  Your query above updates dbusns.thisdate to 31/10/2011 (rather than 01/11/2011) for URN 1.

Comment: @w0051977 And what's the value for the reference in that row?

Comment: I have worked with sql for years. It is one of my main strengths. I am very confused.

Comment: @w0051977 And what is the data type of `created`?, because the above query should work in this situation

Comment: @w0051977 Then can you post some test data for both tables?, because this should be updating the date

Comment: Thanks. The dbusns table contains 104 million rows. The dbcustody contains about 200,000. Isn't the test data in the question enough?

Comment: @w0051977 I meant the data for the particular case we are analizing. As I said, this should be working. Is there any triggers in your table?

Comment: There are no triggers on the table. Could it be the execution plan?

Comment: @w0051977 No, the most likely thing is the data is not what you think it is. Can we see the data for this particular case?

Comment: There is no primary key on the dbcustody table. I bet that is it! What do you think?

Comment: @w0051977 I don't see how **that** would be relevant, but hey, since I can't see your actual data....

Comment: You are right, the derived table returns one date per reference.

Comment: @w0051977 Sorry, can't help you anymore without understanding your actual data

Comment: I tried moving dbcustody to the server containing dbusns. Both your query and my query work. It is the cross database aspect that is causing the problem.

Comment: One server is sql 2005 and the other is sql 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `update` syntax is right, except for one small thing.  Consider this line:

```
update dbusns set thisdate = created from ( . . .
```

The `created` column -- I am guessing -- is in `dbusns`.  So, it is just setting `thisdate` to the created value i the same table.

You can fix this by using a table alias:

```
update dbusns set thisdate = CustodyDateTable.created from ( . . .
```

Comment: I have tried that and the same problem occurs.  Thanks anyway.